# Need solution to run and deploy Spring Cloud Function on AWS Lambda

Tags: maven, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I've been trying to deploy Spring cloud function on AWS as Lambda function, I tried using the POC and followed various articles related to that, however when I run the function on AWS, it keeps giving error - {
"errorMessage": "Failed to discover main class. An attempt was made to discover main class as 'MAIN_CLASS' environment variable, system property as well as entry in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (in that order).",
"errorType": "java.lang.IllegalStateException"
}`

---

```
package org.crds.adapter;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication

@Log4j2

public class AdapterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(AdapterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> greeter(){
        return (input) -> {
            log.info("Hello there");
            return "Hello there ";
        };
    }

}
```

`

References used

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_aws_lambda

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function

Attaching the pom.xml file and the snapshot JAR after the build

Kindly let me know what is missing or how can it be resolved.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.crds</groupId>
    <artifactId>adapter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>adapter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```